# cancellable thread

Tags: gtk

In my C/gtk+ application i read some data with dk_pixbuf_new_from_stream, and i must do it cancellable with GCancellable: where can i find example of using GCancellable?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is create the GCancellable and hand it to the thread, which then calls `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_stream()`. From your main thread, if you want to abort the loading, call `g_cancellable_cancel()` on the same GCancellable instance.